# Can I mock / spy on a variable value that exists in the parent scope of a non-pure function?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

```js
let state = 'Monday';
export function greet() {
  return 'hello ' + state;
}
```

↑ With good coding practice, you wouldn't encounter non-pure functions like this, but for some special reasons I did.

Then, with jest:

```js
import { greet } from './functions';

test('a', () => {
  expect(greet()).toBe('hello Monday');
});

test('b', () => {
  let state = 'Tuesday';
  expect(greet()).toBe('hello Tuesday'); // fail! Still 'hello Monday'
});
```

In this case, how can I mock the state?

Comment: You do not need to mock the state, you can simply mock the greet() and have it set to return the 'hello Tuesday'.  If you need to mock something internal in the function (or class) then you should use dependency injection for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to replace the private variable defined in the module scope with a mocking one.

> The current version of rewire is only compatible with CommonJS modules. see [limitations](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire#limitations)

So below example change the ES module to CommonJS modules.

E.g.
`functions.js`:

```js
let state = 'Monday';
function greet() {
  return 'hello ' + state;
}

exports.greet = greet;
```

`functions.test.js`:

```js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const functions = rewire('./functions');

describe('60763037', () => {
  test('a', () => {
    expect(functions.greet()).toBe('hello Monday');
  });

  test('b', () => {
    functions.__set__('state', 'Tuesday');
    expect(functions.greet()).toBe('hello Tuesday');
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60763037/functions.test.js
  60763037
    ✓ a (3ms)
    ✓ b (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.04s
```